# Automatically checking for input in Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm currently working on a Batch text adventure/RPG to learn a bit more about coding, and I'm trying to implement a auto-check for input (e.g. player types 1, it goes through without having to press enter). I currently have this:

```
echo Type 1 for New Game
echo.
set /p=gamepick
if gamepicker equ 1 goto newgame
if gamepicker neq 1 goto gamepicker
```

Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: `SET /P variable=[promptString]`, i.e. `Set /P "gamepicker=Type 1 for New Game"`. However please be aware that the end user could just hit enter, or could hit other keys which would break your next `if` line, so before you use the input, you need to perform some sort of validation. Alternatively use the probably more suitable `choice` utility. To learn how to use that, open a Command Prompt window, type `choice /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key. _The example in the answer just submitted would fail, if, for example, the end user entered a doublequote!__

Comment: for this type of user input, you should consider using the [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) command.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows command batch files, the following would be the functional code:

```
REM Turn off command echoing to the screen
@ECHO OFF
ECHO.
ECHO.
SET /p GamePick=Type 1 for New Game
IF "%GamePick%"=="1" goto NewGame
REM If the script gets here, the input value was not a 1

:GamePicker
REM Some code to do something
REM and at the end of the code, exit the script
GOTO Exit

:NewGame
REM The input value was a 1 
ECHO We're starting a new game for you!
REM Some game code goes here
REM and at the end of the code, exit the script
GOTO Exit

:Exit
REM This is the end of the script.
```

Comment: This solution does not answer the question. Of key note: `Without the user having to press Enter`. `Set /P` is not the command that should be used for such menus, `Choice` is.